# Switching high side of a circuit with an arduino and two n-channel mosfets

Tags: arduino, mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

hello i have a sevenpointfive to 9 volt power supply and want to power a circuit which needs 5 volts. I have an arduino pro mini(3.3v version) and two n channel mosfets(irlz34n and irlz44n)

i came up with an idea to overcome the problem of the vgs voltage of n channel mosfets on the high side but it doesnt work.

Any suggestion how i could use two n- channel mosfets to build a high side switch for this circuit fed from an arduino pin with 3.3v.

picture explanation: the pulsating power source should illustrate the 3.3 v of the arduino pin and the motor illustrates the load i want to supply (lcd shield) with 5 V. V1 is a power source which puts out 9v. The Mosfets i have are irlz34n and irlz44n.
[image]

Comment: It’s normal to use a p-channel FET for high side switching but if you have a higher voltage available then it’s possible to use an n-channel FET as you suggest.  Depending on your FET, 2.5V between gate and source seems rather low to saturate the device; a 9V supply would be preferable but check the FET datasheet to see what Vgs you need for the desired load current.  Note that the gate of M5 must be actively driven in both directions (high and low).  I imagine that S1 refers to an Arduino I/O pin in reality, a ‘real’ switch as shown in the schematic would require a pull-down resistor.

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick reply. Unfortunately this circuit does not work. I Forgot to mention that that v1 is v2 after a voltage regulator and since there is a common ground problem the m4 mosfet just needs the positive pin of the v2 powersupply

Comment: Nevertheless, you could use a resistor to pull the gate of M4 to 9V and then M5 to pull the gate down to ground, so the circuit could work with minor changes.

Comment: Man thank you so much for trying to help. I didnt really understand how this should work by pulling down or up the gate but i appreciate the attempt to help. Do you have an idea which p-channel mosfet i could use when i go with it. I uploaded a circuit example on how it could look like with a n channel and a p channel mosfet but which ones???

Comment: Well, you obviously need to provide a schematic that uses the correct common ground situation for your voltage supplies. Then, describe exactly what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: There are many, many online resources for high-side switching and P MOSFETs. Why don't you do a little research and come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: i think i would have to upload exact the diagram i plan to use thanks elliot

Comment: We know the supply voltage and the gate voltage that we have available, what’s the load current (roughly) and how fast do you need to switch it?  There are many devices to choose from but we’ll be happy to suggest an inexpensive and easy-to-find one.

Comment: The load current is around 50 mA maximum. Switching speed is very slow. I want to use this circuit to turn on a lcdshield of an arduino maybe every couple of minutes

Comment: Hello again Frog, could you confirm again that your idea would work on the uploaded schematic in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are the parts on hand, this circuit should work. Resistor values are not critical and could be anything between 1K to 100K or so.

Which transistor to use doesn't really matter much. The IRLZ44 has slightly lower RDSon so using that to switch the load is better.

[link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAzENPcFXzCj69sQsNCQxIKTuEJUUNBfm5KQo8BKiwZAJ24qw-A7xq8qYeGwBu4GjRB4L92uai0qxd1RgI2AczsHJyCQYkJvNgB3ULMTV24A7gwhfgEU9UgHH2j4owEVFEUoXOxsCNZUjMrEwLKKl3q5HxLbJrBG8vAjbw9qFt82fUFQkbT3SzhcsbwCgVmSmJ5uBeWUBAjINgAZZtUqEMUBkA4AQwAbAGcGfrYgA)

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much for your support Richard. I can try the suggestions posted here and if it doesnt work i can edit the question and give more details on why it doesnt work.

Comment: could you please recheck the updated schematic in the question and give your oppinions on that?